# Are there any translations of the 14 books of Enki?

Tags: sumerian, translation

Are there any translations of the 14 books of Enki?

I have only found a synopsis of the tablets but can't find any full translations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These "14 tablets" are entirely fictitious, an invention of conspiracy theorist  [Zecharia Sitchin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zecharia_Sitchin)  in his book *The Lost Book of ENKI*.

According to [Mythopedia](https://myths.fandom.com/wiki/14_tablets_of_Enki), which calls the book a "novel":

> The introduction suggests, but does not reveal, that the tablets of Enki were recovered among thousands of other tablets from a library in Nineveh....
> An attestation reveals the protagonist of the novel—a scribe identified as Endubsar, who writes and prepares fourteen tablets for Enki, "Lord of Earth".

This book is a memoir from the point of view of Enki, here reimagined as an "ancient astronaut". Although the book does quote actual ancient sources, they are only there to support the invented narrative.

[This Youtube video](https://youtu.be/lacT--YmV7U) explains how Sitchin was not a professional Assyriologist, but an enthusiast who taught himself Sumerian, and relied upon fundamental translation errors to support his theories.

[This Reddit post by SokarRostau on r/conspiracy](https://www.reddit.com/r/conspiracy/comments/3ymzrs/current_location_of_the_14_tablets_of_enki/) sums it up:

> Where previous works in the series could be described charitably as alternative history, *The Lost Book of Enki* is a work of speculative fiction and it says so on the cover.